Finding the largest $n$ such that for any integer $k\leq n/2$, there are two divisors of $n$ whose difference is $k$

Find the largest $n$ such that for any integer $k\leq n/2$, there are two divisors of $n$ whose difference is $k$.

My attempts:

If $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$, then we have $n_1-n_2=n/p$ where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are divisors of $n$. If we write $n_1=n/a$, then

\begin{equation}\frac{n}{a}+\frac{n}{p}\bigg\vert n,\end{equation}
which simplifies to $a+p|p^2$, forcing $a=p^2-p$. Hence, $p-1|n$. In other words, if $p$ divides $n$, then $p-1$ must also divides $n$. Particularly, $n$ is even.

I also had a look at large difference terms: $n/2-1,n/2-2,n/2-3$ (this makes $3\big\vert n$)

Let $d=d(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n$. Then there are $(d-1)(d-2)/2+1$ useful differences, which is at least $n/2$. This requires $d\geq\sqrt{n}+2$. This should turn into some upper bound of $n$, yet I haven't found a neat way to do this.

My computer says the largest possible $n\leq 5000$ is $24$. And I think this is the final answer.


Any other ideas?

Let us denote $d(n)$ for the number of divisors of $n$. If we can prove $\binom{d(n)}{2}<\frac{n}{2}$ for every $n>1260$ , then together with your search we are done. This is satisfied upto $n=10^8$ and perhaps with the theory about the highly composite numbers , we can finish the proof.

For this purpose , it is sufficient to show $d(n)<\sqrt{n}$ for $n>1260$ which still holds upto $n=10^8$.

Checking the highly composite numbers upto about $2\cdot 10^{481}$ reveals that upto this limit , $d(n)^2<n$ holds for every $n>1260$. Considering that the last entry (magnitude about $2\cdot 10^{481}$) has about $5\cdot 10^{58}$ divisors which is way smaller than the square root , your conjecture that $24$ is the final answer is extremely likely true.

You're close! Iterate your step 2 for large enough $n$.  You claimed that $ 3 \mid n$. Can you show that $ 5 \mid n$? What about $ 7 \mid n$?

@CalvinLin Does that mean there is an easy rigorous proof ? If so, I suggest you post an answer.

I recommend editing the posted question : "....for any integer $~k\leq n/2~$...there are two divisors of $~n$..." : I recommend editing this to "...for any integer $~k~$ such that $~2 \leq k \leq n/2,~$ ...there are two positive divisors of $~n$...".

@Peter Added. Can you review?

Preamble: OP actually has most of the ideas necessary for this solution. The crux was to look at "large difference terms" to conclude that $ m \mid n$ for small enough $m$, and eventually all $m$.
Solution: Show the following.  If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and why you can't push through.
OP has shown that $n $ is even in Step 1, and claims that $ 3 \mid n$ in Step 2. We will not assume these for now.

Check up to $n = 30$, manually verify that $n = 24$ is the largest value that works.

We will prove that no $n> 30 $ works.


The largest factors of $n$ are $n$, possibly $\frac{n}{2}$, and possibly $\frac{n}{3}$.

For any $k < n/2$, it cannot be written as a difference involving $n$.

For $ k = \lceil n/2 \rceil - 1 > n/3$, this can only be obtained as $(n/2) - (1)$, so $2 \mid n$.

We henceforth assume that $n$ is even.
Note: This argument is much easier than OP's step 1.


In fact, for any $ n/3 < k < n/2$, it must involve a factor larger than $n/3$ that is not $n$, which leaves us only with $n/2$.

Let $ k = n/2 - j$ for $j  = 1$ to $ \frac{n}{2} - \lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil$,  then $ j \mid n$, so $LCM(1, 2, \ldots , \frac{n}{2} - \lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil ) \mid n$.
Note: I believe this is similar to OP's argument that $ 3 \mid n$, though details are lacking.


Since $n \geq 30$, so $\frac{n}{2} - \lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil \geq 5$, $LCM(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) = 60$,  thus $60 \mid n$.

If you're not comfortable proving the ceiling inequality, use a larger starting value.
We henceforth assume that $3 \mid n$. EG We can remove the ceiling function as a simplification.


Since $n \geq 60$, so $\frac{n}{2} - \frac{n}{3} \geq 10$, $LCM(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) = 2520$,  thus $2520 \mid n$.

Iterate this procedure to show that no  $n> 30$ works.

If $ 6x \mid n $, then $ n \geq 6x$, and  $\frac{n}{2} - \frac{n}{3} \geq x $, and every prime power up to $x$ must divide $n$.
Convince yourself that we can increase the threshold. This is "obvious" so I'd leave you to work out your preferred  details.

IE After 2520, we have all prime powers up to $ \frac{2520}{6} = 420$, which is a huge number.
EG $\frac{ x(x-1)(x-2)}{2} \mid n$, $\frac{ x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{12} \mid n$.





